# Adding float: left breaks list

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a visual element called a "plan", that is listed in a html page. Each "plan" has a small table and an image, that i want to show side by side. Without any styling it looks like this: http://jsfiddle.net/DCTwd/1/

I thought i could use `float: left` in table and image to make them display in the same row, but that doesn't work. Isn't it possible to use `float: left` inside a `li`? Else how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no need for ancient `float:left;`, when `display:inline-block;` is your best friend!

[your updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DCTwd/4/). this is an overly simple example, so your actual CSS should involve class-based rather than element-based CSS, but it gets the point across.

Notice the fallback of `zoom:1; *display:inline;` for IE7-, and `vertical-align:middle;` for aesthetics. You can also use `top` or `bottom`, whatever works for you.

Answer (score 2):

I would use an `inline-table` which is well supported as of CSS2.1:

```
table {
    display: inline-table;
}
```

I build a demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/cYDUC/

You need to pay attention to padding and margin around your `ul` and `li` elements and hide the bullet on the left (unless you want to display it).

If you need to support IE7, you can use `display: inline` and adjust padding and margin around the elements accordingly.